# Application hangs when tried to create AVAsset object

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avasset

I am trying to play video using AVPlayer. Problem is application freezes when ever i try to create an AVAsset object here is my code snippet

```
let url = videoUrl.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
print("loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys - \(url)")
let asset = AVAsset(URL:NSURL(string: url!)!)
print("asset created")
```

UPDATED CODE

```
let strURL = videoUrl.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
print("url string is created - \(strURL!)")
if let url = NSURL(string: strURL!)
{
    print("it is valid url")
    let asset = AVAsset(URL:url)
    print("asset created")
}
print("after if condition")
```

I can see first log but second one is never executed. Please someone help me what i am missing here.

Comment: You should first ensure your URL is valid - that is, check the result of the init function `NSURL(string:)`. The way you create the URL string is not appropriate to create a valid URL, instead use `NSURLComponents`.  Don't use force unwrapped optionals (unless out _know_ they are not `nil`), instead check if they are not `nil`.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper tested as u suggested, but still having same issue, updated my question with new code snippet.

Comment: So, when the second print statement (`print("it is valid url")` is _not_ executed, then the URL variable could quite obviously not be created successfully - e.g. `url` equals `nil`. Now, again: "The way you create the URL string is not appropriate to create a valid URL, instead use NSURLComponents. "

Comment: here the log "url string is created - https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/appnamehere/1a.m4v
it is valid url"

Comment: So, we have a _remote_ url. Note that fully loading an Asset may take time and is performed asynchronously with the `init` function. Accessing member variables or obtaining the values for keys is _synchronous_ and may block the current thread until they are available.  There's also the possibility to get asynchronously notified when certain values are available. See further details in the documentation. For now, until you provide more details - the issue is not clear.

Comment: If the issue is due to resource loading, you may try to use `AVURLAsset` instead of `AVAsset`. Then obtain the `resourceLoader` and assign a delegate implementing the delegate methods. See [AVAssetResourceLoader](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetResourceLoader_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)AVAssetResourceLoader).